# How can I test Qt4 application for correct QNetworkProxy work?

Tags: qt, http, proxy, socks

I create a Qt4.8x program for Windows which accesses certain site using `QNetworkAccessManager`. At the moment this utility work directly. But I need to add HTTP and SOCKS5 proxy support using `QNetworkProxy`. Proxy will work on the customer's machine.
How can I check correct proxy work on my own laptop? If we have smtp4dev utility for email, then what simple proxy tester for Windows would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you check that your program correctly uses the proxy server you configure by looking at the output of the command [netstat](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/netstat.mspx?mfr=true). It is both available on Windows, Linux and OS X.

Just add an option to display the PID of the process that open the connection to check for those open by your program.

If your proxy works you will only see connections opened to its address.